# Update specific cell in Dataset with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datatable, dataset

I was wonder how I'd update a specific well in a database (the balance cell), when all I know is the users account number.

I don't know where about in the database this will be. I just know the account number exists as I've logged in through it.

I need to use LINQ for this, and I've tried querying the database to find the balance. Although, I want to update the balance to a specific value, not find the current value.

In SQL, I'd do something like:

```
UPDATE UserData
SET Balance = some value in this case an int being passed in
WHERE AccNo = the accountNumber variable stored in a global class
```

But the problem is the value is stored in a dataset as the client is working offline with the data. His dataset is updated in the SQL database once he logs out. I was going to do this by retrieving everything from the database and going an update/merge statement.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: DataSet does not contains cells. it is a collection of data tables

Comment: I've been able to retrieve a specific balance within the dataset this is why I thought it had cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Linq-To-DataSet` is a subset of `Linq-To-Objects`. You can use it to *query* a `DataSet`/`DataTable`, but you can't use it to update the rows.

So you could search the relevant `DataRows` with LINQ and then use a loop to update them.

```
DataTable tblUserData = dataSet.Tables["UserData"];
var rowsWithAccount = from row in tblUserData.AsEnumerable()
                      where row.Field<string>("AccountNumber") == accountNumber // replace `<string>` with the right type
                      select row;
foreach(DataRow row in rowsWithAccount)
    row.SetField("Balance", newBalance);
```

Once the value is updated you can use a `SqlDataAdapter` to update the database:

[Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is working with a slight modification, so I've accepted it as the answer although attached my modification. I changed where row.Field<string>("AccountNumber") == accountNumber to Convert.ToString(row["AccountNo"]) == accountNumber and it works without the string error.

Comment: @Paul: then use the correct datatype(i've commented it already with `// replace <string> with the right type`). I guess it's a number, probably an integer. Then use `where row.Field<int>("AccountNumber") == int.Parse(accountNumber)` or `row.Field<int>("AccountNumber").ToString() == accountNumber`